# setting compound drawable to different TextViews

Tags: android

In the following code I have 5 TextViews in which I try to set a compound drawable for each one of them.

However the drawable is drawn only on the first one! WHY, and how to fix it !?

```
if(number >= 1210 && number <= 1215){
    ist1_1210.setCompoundDrawablesWithIntrinsicBounds(R.drawable.update_icon, 0, 0,0);
    ist1_1210.setPadding(10, 0, 0, 0);
    ist1_1210.setCompoundDrawablePadding(-45);
    System.out.println("ist1_1210 is supposed to be running");
}

if(number >= 1220 && number <= 1225){
    //ist1_1220.setTextColor(Color.GREEN);
    ist1_1220.setCompoundDrawablesWithIntrinsicBounds(R.drawable.update_icon, 0, 0,0);
    ist1_1220.setPadding(10, 0, 0, 0);
    ist1_1220.setCompoundDrawablePadding(-45);
    System.out.println("ist1_1220 is supposed to be running");
}

if(number >= 1230 && number <= 1235){
    //ist1_1230.setTextColor(Color.GREEN);
    ist1_1230.setCompoundDrawablesWithIntrinsicBounds(R.drawable.update_icon, 0, 0,0);
    ist1_1230.setPadding(10, 0, 0, 0);
    ist1_1230.setCompoundDrawablePadding(-45);
}

if(number >= 1240 && number <= 1245){
    //ist1_1240.setTextColor(Color.GREEN);
    ist1_1240.setCompoundDrawablesWithIntrinsicBounds(R.drawable.update_icon, 0, 0,0);
    ist1_1240.setPadding(10, 0, 0, 0);
    ist1_1240.setCompoundDrawablePadding(-45);
}

if(number >= 1250 && number <= 1255){
    //ist1_1250.setTextColor(Color.GREEN);
    ist1_1250.setCompoundDrawablesWithIntrinsicBounds(R.drawable.update_icon, 0, 0,0);
    ist1_1250.setPadding(10, 0, 0, 0);
    ist1_1250.setCompoundDrawablePadding(-45);
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well without more information it's impossible to say, but I can tell you that unless this is running more than once, only one of these `if` statements will execute. `number` can't possibly satisfy more than one of these conditions.

Comment: this code is inside a for-loop and since I'm not using if-then-else this should execute all the if statements right ?!

Comment: That would depend on your for-loop conditions.